# How to select all column from multiple tables in codeigniter using join?

Tags: codeigniter, join, mysqli

I have 4 tables like this:
[image: Database structure]

Now, I want to select all columns from all tables where `model.featured=1`. i.e.

```
model.id
model.name
model_attributes.id
model_attributes.attributes_value
model_images.id
model_images.model_images
attributes.id
attributes.name
attributes.value
```

I can only do basic level queries and I'm not sure if I'm anywhere near to the solution but this is what I have tried (returns nothing):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('model');
$this->db->join('model_images','model.id = model_images.model_id','RIGHT');
$this->db->join('model_attributes','model.id = model_attributes.model_id','RIGHT');
$this->db->join('attributes','model_attributes.attributes_id = attributes.id','RIGHT');
$this->db->where('model.featured', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

How do I achieve what I want ? Or, is there any other better methods to do it ?

Comment: What database software are you using to view those tables? Just curious. I use navicat. Though Ive not tried the `model` system yet.

Comment: yeah, it's https://dbdesigner.net

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN?

Comment: Can you show me the complete query ?

Answer (score 0):

// try this query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('model');
$this->db->join('model_images','model_images.model_id = model.id');
$this->db->join('model_attributes','model_attributes.model_id = model.id');
$this->db->join('attributes','attributes.id = model_attributes.attributes_id');
$this->db->where('model.featured','1');
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below mentioned solution.

```
$this->db->select('model.*,model_images.*,model_attributtes.*, attributes.*'):
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Nope. Its only selects the given fields but not from all table.

Comment: Okay, Please find my another answer

Answer (score 0):

Please go through below solution. If multiple table has same column name then you have to give alias for each column name which have same name in both the table. because by default CI merge all column name and generate result.

```
$this->db->select('*,c.name as c_name,s.name as s_name');
$this->db->from('country c');
$this->db->join('state s', 'c.id = s.country_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
```